# Regex returns a match in Javascript, but not C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a RegEx that I'm using to get the version number from iOS user agent strings.

My RegEx is `/OS ([0-9_]+)/g`, and it's being applied to a user agent string like `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53`

I've tested this on an online RegEx tool, and it claims it should work as I intend. My test is [here](http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/1). I've tried it in Javascript, and I get a match. I've then put it into C#, and I don't get a match. I'm using `Regex.Match(...)`:

```
string uaString = @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53";

bool matched = Regex.IsMatch(uaString, @"/(?:OS )([0-9_]+)/g"); // is false

Match match = Regex.Match(uaString, @"/(?:OS )([0-9_]+)/g");
string osVersion = match.Groups[0].Value; // is ""
```

I'm not very knowledgeable about Regular Expressions, and can't see what I'm doing wrong. Most of the pages I've read are about people having issues going from C# to JS, and hitting issues due to JS not supporting everything that C# does. Is there a difference in syntax between the two that would cause this?

Comment: Try to debug your regex with http://regexhero.net/

Comment: Both that and dotnetfiddle.net from Yuliam's answer look really helpful. Wish I'd found them a couple of hours ago :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `/` and `/g`

```
@"(?:OS )([0-9_]+)"
```

Output

```
OS 7_0
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BEpm6N)

If you want to use global search, use [**`Regex.Matches`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it will return more than one matches if any.

> Searches an input string for all occurrences of a regular expression
>   and returns all the matches.